problem while in apk file map not working in react native
import MapView, { AnimatedRegion, Animated, MarkerAnimated,Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

<Animated style={styles.map}
                region={mapRegion}
            >
                {dropLocation.latitude != 0 && dropLocation.latitude ? (<MapViewDirections
                    origin={pickupLocation}
                    destination={dropLocation}
                    apikey={map_key}
                    strokeWidth={5}
                    strokeColor="#4338e8"
                />) : null}
                <MarkerAnimated 
                    coordinate={
                        pickupLocation
                    }
                    ref={pickupMarker}
                    image={require('../../assets/icons/pick_pin.png')}
                ></MarkerAnimated >
                <MarkerAnimated 
                    coordinate={ 
                        dropLocation
                    } 
                    ref={dropMarker}
                    image={require('../../assets/icons/drop_pin.png')}
                ></MarkerAnimated >
                <MarkerAnimated 
                    coordinate={
                        dropLocation
                    }
                    ref={dropMarker}
                    image={require('../../assets/icons/car_Icon.png')}
                ></MarkerAnimated >
            </Animated>

Its finally working in expo , but with apk file it is not working ,i will go inside that map screen it quite the whole application ,please help me resolve this issue.

Have you checked the reason of crash on logcat?
